# Centering a child div based on the parent div

Tags: css

I have a parent div and a child div.I would like to center to know if i could express the width and the height of the child as a percent of the parent,for instance

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Horizontal center a  div</title>
<style type='text/css'>
.one{
width:800px;
height:100px;
background-color:grey;
}
.two{
margin-top:30px;
margin-bottom:30px;
min-height:40px;
margin-left:30px;
width:90px;
background-color:pink;
display:inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one">
<div class="two">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/3qRgH/

The outer div(parent) has a `height of 100px` and my child div has a `height of 40px`.I would like to center my child inside the parent theme,so,`100px - 40px = 60px` and i divide the 60px twice and assign the child div `margin-top:30px` and `margin-bottom:30px;`.I however would like to express the margins in percentage form.How would i express the margins in %.

Comment: If .one width is constant, you could do the math and express it with percent, if variable you could use javascript to change it in realtime. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: In that case the easy answer would be 30% but that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the divs this way (edited) :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Horizontal center a  div</title>
<style type='text/css'>
.one{
width: 800px;
background-color: grey;
}
.two{
min-height: 40px;
margin: 30% 355px;
width: 90px;
background-color: pink;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one">
<div class="two">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3qRgH/2/

Is this what you 're asking?

Comment: I am trying to avoid display:block;.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/5AZJD/

That seems to work but i haven't proved it

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Horizontal center a  div</title>
<style type='text/css'>
.one{
position:relative;
width:800px;
height:100px;
background-color:grey;
}
.two{
position:absolute;
top:30%;
bottom:30%;
min-height:40px;
margin-left:30px;
width:90px;
background-color:pink;
display:inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one">
<div class="two">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```